# Unable to delete or formatt the unknown partition

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, android, gparted, sd-card

[image]

I want to delete both partition and format it to fat32 , but my problem is cant delete the unknown partition as you can see in the Gaparted picture. 
I have no idea how these partition has been created, lately i was using this SD card in my Android.
please help to format or reset it hard

```
sudo parted /dev/mmcblk0p1 mklabel msdos mkpartfs primary fat32 0% 100% print
```

Output:

```
    Error: Partition(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51,
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/mmcblk0p1
have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the
change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old
partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making
further changes.
parted: invalid token: mkpartfs
Ignore/Cancel? Ignore
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

[image]

Comment: So what's the problem? Do you really use Ubuntu 12.04 in 2017? If so, it's not supported here!

Comment: i cant use the SD card, i have only access to fat32 partition.

Comment: This is information that belongs to your question, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/949288/edit) and tell us exactly what problems you're experiencing.

Comment: I want to delete both partition and format it to fat32 , but my problem is cant delete the unknown partition as you can see in the Gaparted picture.

Comment: `wipefs -a /dev/mmcblk0`, or maybe `wipefs -a /dev/mmcblk0p1; wipefs -a /dev/mmcblk0p2; wipefs -a /dev/mmcblk0`

Comment: Doesn't work still have those partition !!...

Comment: Then your card is probably bricked/dead.

Answer (score 0):

**Always backup your data before playing around with partitioning!**

In GParted, choose “Device” → “Create Partition Table…” to format the whole
drive.

[image]

After that you can create your new `fat32` partition.

---

Alternatively, you can do the same in a terminal using:

```
sudo parted -s /dev/mmcblk0 mklabel msdos mkpartfs primary fat32 0% 100% print
```

This does the following:

- `-s` do not prompt for user intervention
- `mklabel msdos` create a new partition table of type `msdos`
- `mkpartfs primary fat32 0% 100%` create a new primary partition with file system `fat32` from 0 to 100% of the device size
- `print` print the new partition table

Comment: Not working. Restored to same as it was before

Comment: Did you try the terminal command in my answer? If it doesn't help, please add the output to your question in a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: please check the error sir

Comment: Why did you replace `/dev/mmcblk0` with `/dev/mmcblk0p1`? Try again with `/dev/mmcblk0` please.

Comment: Not worked printing me the Manual page of  parted

Comment: Usage: parted [OPTION]... [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]...]...]
Apply COMMANDs with PARAMETERS to DEVICE.  If no COMMAND(s) are given, run in
so on ....